# Como deixar uma aplicação php, rodando no pc do cliente mesmo se a conexão com o servidor cair?

Tags: php, mysql

Retificando a pergunta anterior, informo que **a minha ideia é deixar o cliente navegar entre páginas da aplicação**, efetuar registos localmente, e recuperar esses dados quando a conexão restabelecer.

Comment: "PHP offline" é meio esquisito. O que você pode fazer é rodar o servidor PHP  no próprio cliente. Seria legal você ser mais específico na pergunta, pois já tem 3 votos para fechamento como "ampla demais". Lembre-se de que você pode [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar os detalhes mais específicos da aplicação.

Comment: Cara o php é uma linguagem "servi side" ela roda no servidor a única forma de você deixar o sistema funcionando em offline é utilizando o javascript e html que rodam nas plataforma "Client Side" porem para salvar em banco de dados de qualquer forma você precisaria do php em um servidor local

Comment: Tem que explicar melhor, **php offine** quer dizer o que, deixar uma aplicação rodando somente em rede sem internet ? Ficou meio dificil de entender, será que esta falando do banco de dados indisponivel dai fazer a persistencia em outro lugar até que haja disponibilidade de fazer a conexão com o banco e dai gravar o que estaria em "buffer" ou algo do genero... ficou bem dificil de entender viu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso queira deixar seu webapp disponivel mesmo se o servidor estiver off ou o cliente sem internet, você deve usar **local storage** do **HTML5**. E claro, lembre-se de só usar o local storage para salvar dados do próprio usuario, como id, e nome de usuário, nunca salve senha ou dados pessoais.
Lembre-se de utilizar javascript no cliente para detectar enventos offline ok?

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer, não é fácil de obter. Eu entendo a motivação (manter a aplicação disponível quando Internet ou servidor falharem) mas a arquitetura da aplicação teria de ser consideravelmente mais complexa para atingir este resultado. Imagine por exemplo a situação: o sistema cai fora do ar, dois usuários alteram o mesmo cadastro enquanto o sistema está fora. Como esas alterações conflitantes vão ser conciliadas? É uma amostra do tipo de coisa com que um sistema distribuído tem de lidar.